# Choosing Specific Files from Time Machine After Reformat

Tags: hard-drive, itunes, osx-mountain-lion, time-machine

I had been using Time Machine for full back-ups of my MacBook Pro for a couple of years. Today, I reformatted my internal drive with the intention of building it up piece by piece, so I opted to NOT restore everything with a Time Machine update when I was given the option.

The ONLY thing I need from Time Machine is my iTunes library.

I still have the external drive with all of the old Time Machine back-ups, but I don't know how to access them -- I'm scared that designating it now as my Time Machine drive again will knock out all of the previous updates and I'll lose everything.

Is there away to mount my Time Machine drive that will without-a-doubt allow me to view the previous back-ups and select my iTunes Library?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just copy the iTunes directory from Finder. It should be somewhere like `/Volumes/Time Machine/Backups.backupdb/Your Mac/2013-09-09-181210/Macintosh HD/Users/username/Music/`.